Connection Error: to virtual data warehourse via JDBC by PieProxy connection pool
When I used PieCloudDB, I met with some connection issues. Before, I used NodePort to connect to my virtual data warehourse and it could be easily connected via JDBC.
However recently I have tried several times to use the PieProxy connection pool but all failed to connect. Could anyone give me some tips to fix this problem?

Check the (error) logfiles

There are two points that you have to pay attention to when usinf the JDBC to connect virtual data warehourse via PieProxy:
1.When accessing the virtual data warehouse through PieProxy, SSL authentication connection is enabled by default. If you are connecting with a password, you need to disable this access method.
2.You have to make sure that the connection information of virtual data warehouse is correct.
So I recommend you to write the code as follows :


jdbc:postgresql://<Warehouse_IP>:<port>/<database_name>?sslmode=disable&options=-c%20warehouse%3D<Warehouse_ID>



